# JDT SearchEngine throws a NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to use JDT SearchEngine to find references to a given object. But I'm getting a "NullPointerException" while invoking the "search" method of org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine.

Following is the error trace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.findMatches(BasicSearchEngine.java:214)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.search(BasicSearchEngine.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine.search(SearchEngine.java:582)

And following is the method I'm using to perform search:

```java
private static void search(String elementName) { //elementName -> a method Name
        try {
            SearchPattern pattern = SearchPattern.createPattern(elementName, IJavaSearchConstants.METHOD,
                    IJavaSearchConstants.REFERENCES, SearchPattern.R_PATTERN_MATCH);

            IJavaSearchScope scope = SearchEngine.createWorkspaceScope();

            SearchRequestor requestor = new SearchRequestor() {
                @Override
                public void acceptSearchMatch(SearchMatch match) {
                    System.out.println("Element - " + match.getElement());
                }
            };

            SearchEngine searchEngine = new SearchEngine();
            SearchParticipant[] searchParticipants = new SearchParticipant[] { SearchEngine
                    .getDefaultSearchParticipant() };
            searchEngine.search(pattern, searchParticipants, scope, requestor, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Refer the "Variables" window of the following snapshot to check the values of the arguments passing to the "searchEngine.search()":

[image]

I think the the issue is because of the value of "scope" [Highlighted in 'BLACK' above].
Which means "SearchEngine.createWorkspaceScope()" doesn't return expected values in this case.

**NOTE:** Please note that this is a part of my program which runs as a stand-alone java program (not an eclipse plugin) using JDT APIs to parse a given source code (using JDT-AST).

Isn't it possible to use JDT SearchEngine in such case (non eclipse plugin program), or is this issue due to some other reason? 
Really appreciate your answer on this.

Comment: My suggestion would be to create a stand-alone plug-in program, using tools such as Eclipse RCP. This will keep the application as standalone and you will also be able to access the workspace via configuration files, thus enabling the use of the JDT search engine.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But in my case, I can't limit my implementation only for Eclipse projects. Basically, my application handles a given java source code base and it should be capable of handling any type of java sources. So eclipse workspace configuration files may not be there in a given java project as an input to my application. However your suggestion might be useful for some other cases where that kind of a limitation is not there.

Comment: Then as Anrew Eisenberg suggested, you can go for a Custom Search Engine solution, probably using the ASTVisitor pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  You cannot use the search engine without openning a workspace.  The reason is that the SearchEngine relies on the eclipse filesystem abstraction (`IResource`, `IFile`, `IFolder`, etc.).  This is only available when the workspace is open.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. As you think, is there any possibility I can do something like, providing the relevant inputs and populate the mentioned filesystem abstractions (e.g.: by providing classpath, source/binary paths)? I mean overriding the information loading from eclipse with an external logic.

Comment: In theory, it's possible (anything is theoretically possible to program), but the interfaces to code to are so large and complex, I would strongly recommend against it.  If your projects are not too large, then you would be better off rolling your own solution and creating a custom search engine that just searches through every class file in your project.

Comment: Thanks and really appreciate your expertise info. on resolving the doubts.