# Determine all Strings (dynamically built and literals) passed to a method in Java

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt, static-code-analysis

I am trying to build a static code analysis, that allows to collect all Strings passed to a function without running the code. I am using Eclipse JDT (3.10.0) to parse the code.

**Assumptions/Precodinditions:**

- Every passed argument can be resolved to a String literal
- The value is not saved to any (non-static) fields and then passed on in another call
- All callers can be identified and visited by the parser
- The MethodInvocation of the examined method is already identified

**What i have:**

At the moment i am able to identify all MethodInvocations on that particular Method and therefore am able to collect all arguments passed as StringLiterals.
I am able to see all argument Types but, of course, cannot determine the value of parameters, fields, objects etc. as the value binding would only be available at runtime.

**The Problem**

Under the assumption, that every single passed Argument (no matter the Type) is at some time resolvable to a StringLiteral or a Concatenation of StringLiterals, i should be able to determine the distinct set of all Values which are passed to this method by the program.
Is there a way, to recursively determine the String value of all method calls without following every stacktrace and manually implementing the logic for every occurence?

**Imagine the following examples:**

```
public class IAmAnalysed{
    public void analysedMethod(String argument){
        //do something useful
    }
}

//Values in a map
hashMap.put("test", "TestString");
hashMap.put("test2", "TestString2");
for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : hashMap.entrySet()) {
    iAmAnalysed.analysedMethod(e.getValue);
}

//util method
public void util(String argument){
    iAmAnalysed.analysedMethod(argument + "utilCalled");  
}
util("TestString3")
```

**This should give me the following set of values:**

```
TestString
TestString2
TestString3utilCalled
```

The only appraoch i can think of (using Eclipse JDT) is to add every argument that is no StringLiteral to a working Set and start one more iteration with the ASTParser to determine where the passed value is set, or where it comes from. Then i add this location to the workingSet and iterate once more. This at the end should lead me to all possible arguments.
Unfortunately with this approach i would have to implement logic for every single possible way the value could be passed (imagine all the other possibilities next to the two above)

Answer (score 2):

Examining all possible data flows into a given method is not generally feasible by static analysis. The approach you outline *can* work for a small group of programs, until you hit, e.g., recursion, at what point the thing will blow up.

Maybe a comprehensive test suite will give better results than static analysis on this one.

Comment: This is not supposed to be a general solution. The callees of the function are all resolvable and, in practice, will not exceed a particular stack. Recursion is not to be expected. Basically we want to validate if string ressources used to call the functions are present in the initial dataset of our database. So there is a finite set of input data with a particular ruleset how they can be formed. Testing via Test Suite would be possible but is way more time consuming, even in developement.

Comment: General solution and one example are just two extremes on a long scale. If you are confident that you will not encounter "complex" program structures, go ahead. But as the question already indicates, every language feature of Java will multiply the complexity of your tool. Should you handle if-else? switch? all kinds of loops? try-catch? StringBuilder operations? Etc. This may or may not blow up for you. If you proceed: Have you considered using the SearchEngine to find all callers of a given method - rather than traversing the full AST for each iteration?

Comment: I assume by SearchEngine you mean the Usage Search in my IDE? The question is, if there is a smarter way to do this rather than risking it to blow up. The alternative is manually evaluating every possible caller or complete refactoring of the system. Both take a lot of time and won't be possible in the near future. The tool should basically be a replacement for manually searching all the callers

Comment: `org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine` is a class in JDT/Core that you may use to automate searching for callers similar to Search or Call Hierarchy in the IDE.

Comment: Do you have a practical example how to use it? I found this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019761/jdt-searchengine-throws-a-nullpointerexception) where they state you have to open the workspace context. This seems to me as quite some work regarding to the examples I found

Comment: It depends: If you implement your tool as an Eclipse plug-in then everything nicely falls into place since the workspace is already there and accessible via API. If your's  must be a standalone tool, you'd have to do more legwork before you can leverage search functionality. In the end it's the purpose of an IDE to nicely *integrate* many development tools :)

Comment: yes, that's exactly the problem. The tool is supposed to run as a step of the qa process and therefore cannot be a IDE plugin.

Comment: If you don't mind doing everything via AST traversals, you should be fine. Otherwise, if you want to use search (for callers), then you need an indexed workspace. Even the latter option can be used in a standalone tool (perhaps packaged as an Eclipse "application"), but as said, you'll have to manually perform some of the steps that are given when operating within the IDE. These are just the design options you have, and it's you who has to pick one of them :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Honestly there was no solution to my problem, but i will be trying to shift the problem to the development process instead. Might not make my boss happy, but surely will take less effort.